# make php_value conditional in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need to set the php_value session.save_path in .htaccess.
This seems to require a full path, a relative path doesn't seem to work.

My webapplication runs on both Windows and Linux servers and I'd like to keep the .htaccess file the same on both systems, for deployment reasons.

Is it possible to reference the directory where .htaccess is, in the .htaccess file itself, something like this :

php_value session.save_path  "<%systempath>/sessions"

with <%systempath> being automatically filled in on each system ?

Comment: Interesting question. It might be possible using environment variables - I don't know

Comment: Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_env.html#setenv

Answer (score 2):

You can automatically prepend a php file which will configure php with ini_set()

```
# .htaccess
php_value auto_prepend_file "autoprepend.php"
```

Then:

```
// autoprepend.php
ini_set('session.save_path', __DIR__ . '/sessions');
```

This way it will work for any php script within the directory.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think this is possible with any Apache directive.

But you can do that with PHP:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', dirname(__FILE__).'/sessions');
```

Here `__FILE__` is the [magic constant](http://php.net/language.constants.predefined) that holds the file system path to the current PHP script file and [`dirname`](http://php.net/dirname) returns the parent directory of that file.

Comment: Thanx but I'd much rather do it in .htaccess since I have multiple scripts that use sessions. With .htaccess I'd only have to set this path in one place...

Comment: +1 @Dylan: Apache does not support variables usage in .htaccess. `mod_env` allows you to set (only) environment variables, and `mod_rewrite` allows you to use them in rewrite rules and conditions, but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I know you can use some environment variables.

You can check if it will posible or not with

```
%{ENV:variable}
```

Comment: Works only in `mod_rewrite` unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

in apache .htaccess for example apply php_value only a php files.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ".php$" IS_PHP
<If "-T env('IS_PHP')">
    php_value auto_prepend_file "./init.php"
</If>
```

Comment: on windows **SetEnvIf** not work for me. However, PHP (with `var_dump(getenv('IS_PHP'));
`) show **IS_PHP = true**